# Managing Dependencies in an R Package: Including 'ggplot2' and 'rlang' in 'Suggests' and 'requireNamespace'

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-package, rlang

I have a package where I want to optionally utilize `ggplot2` if the user already has it installed. Since `ggplot2` is not essential for the package's core functionality, I've included it in the `Suggests` section of the package's description file.

Within the package, I plan to use the following code snippet:

```
if (requireNamespace("ggplot2", quietly = TRUE)) {
  ggplot2::ggplot(ggplot2::mpg) + 
    ggplot2::geom_bar(ggplot2::aes(x = rlang::.data$drv)) 
}
```

I have two questions:

1. Given that `ggplot2` already depends on `rlang`, is it necessary to also include `rlang` in the `Suggests` section of the package's description, even though I'm explicitly using it as shown above?
2. Is it enough to only require `ggplot2`, or do I also need to explicitly require `rlang` like this:

```
if (requireNamespace("ggplot2", quietly = TRUE)) {
  ...
}
```

or

```
if (requireNamespace("ggplot2", quietly = TRUE) && 
    requireNamespace("rlang", quietly = TRUE)) {
  ...
}
```

Comment: I do not consider myself a `rpackage`-guru (and struggle through my first attempts). In a nutshell, I would run the R CMD CHECK which will tell you what is missing or give you a warning. From my understanding `suggests` are not critical. Thus, I could picture that the 1st variant may only throw a warning - if at all. The code appears legit and would run (as rlang will be there due to ggplot). As this struggling/newcomer to package development, however, I would opt for the 2nd version along the lines of "... everytime I use double-colons, make sure they are in the DESCRIPTION".

Comment: It's not necessary to add `rlang` to Suggests or to use `requireNamespace()`. However, `rlang::.data` will not work. Simply use `.data` and define it as a global variable. From the docs: 1. *Do not refer to rlang::.data with the ⁠rlang::⁠ qualifier in data masking code. Use the unqualified .data symbol that is automatically put in scope by data-masking functions.*  And 2. *R does not have any way of knowing about the presence or absence of .data in a particular scope so you need to import it explicitly or equivalently declare it with utils::globalVariables(".data").*.